# Presto query (optimization): check if an array contains certain element and count it

Tags: sql, presto

I have the following PRESTO query to count the elements in `my_array` column

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total_count,
    COUNT_IF(any_match(my_array, x -> x LIKE '%dog%')) AS dog_count,
    COUNT_IF(any_match(my_array, x -> x LIKE '%cat%')) AS cat_count
FROM my_table
```

`my_table` is only 5000 lines, and each `my_array` is less than 10 elements. However, the query is extremely slow. I am wondering is there a way to optimize the above query? Thanks!

Comment: How much slower is the query with just the `count(*)`?  Maybe your expectations about what should be fast are not correct.

Comment: The performance also highly depends on how the underlying data is stored. Also, you may just try to use `count(1)` instead of `count(*)`. Would be also good to know the current execution time and your expectation.

Comment: Which connector provides `my_table`? Can you post the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE <your query>`?